# Udp client thread not reusable

Tags: java, multithreading, udpclient

I'm developing a simple UDP communication software to communicate with my robot.

I've been able to use this code to send the first packet but when I try to send the second it does not send neither does it give me errors, what did I do wrong?

EDIT : The problem is I can't use the send void twice.

Code :

Send Void:

```
public static void Send(String Message)
{
    Client Clt = new Client();
    Clt.Message = Message;
    Clt.start();
}
```

Client :

```
public class Client extends Thread {

    public String Message;

    public void run()   
    {
            PrintStream myPS = null;
            try {
                myPS = new PrintStream(Start.CltSkt.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            myPS.println(Message);
            try {
                finalize();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

EDIT 2 (Problem Solved) :

thanks to everyone that answered/commented the questions especially to EJP.

The problem was : 
I was not using a DatagramSocket so I ended up with this :

```
public static void Send(String Message)
    {
            InetAddress Ip = null;
            DatagramSocket datagramSocket = null;
            try {
                datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            } catch (SocketException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Start.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            byte[] buffer = Message.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket packet;
            try {
                Ip = InetAddress.getByName(CltIp);
            } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Start.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, Ip, Integer.parseInt(CltPort));
            try {
                datagramSocket.send(packet);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Start.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    }
```

I was not awere of the the use with datagram sockets! Now I'm :)

Comment: by does not send you mean that the server doesnt receive it?

Comment: yes but the server is running ok because when I use an external software to send it receives with no problems

Comment: You don't need to start a new thread per send. DatagramSockets don't have output streams, so how exactly are you using UDP? Please clarify. NB you should ***certainly not*** call *finalize()* yourself.

Comment: ok I'll remove the finalize() and i'll also take a look at the DatagramSockets Thanks

Comment: So are you or are you not using UDP? It's possible with the code you showed, but it isn't likely. In any case there's not enough code exhibited here to answer your question.

Comment: Im pretty sure its UDP

Comment: Is there any way you could show a bit more code? Specifically, the piece that calls "Send"? This seems like an incredible amount of overhead to send a single UDP packet.

Comment: Also, I think the problem might be really simple -- just add `myPS.flush()` followed by `myPS.close()` in the `run()` method of Client. This will force the data in the stream buffer to get written to the underlying protocol, or whatever `Start.CltSkt.getOutputStream()` represents.

Comment: @ProgrammerDan that solved too but seams like I was not actually sending UDP packets

Comment: Perfect, glad @EJP's suggestion cleared it up!